# Does CSF-LFD include a Fail2Ban analogue or should include Fail2Ban at all?

Tags: fail2ban

I am not of the field of IS and [After reading this CSF-LFD installation document](https://download.configserver.com/csf/install.txt), I've installed CSF-LFD via:

```
cd /usr/src
sudo rm -fv csf.tgz
sudo wget https://download.configserver.com/csf.tgz
sudo tar -xzf csf.tgz
cd csf
sudo sh install.sh
sudo sed -i 's/TESTING === "1"/TESTING === "0"/g' /etc/csf/csf.conf
sudo csf -r
sudo perl /usr/local/csf/bin/csftest.pl
```

---

1. The article displays this installation as dealing with "CSF" but the **Uninstall chapter** of the article says that when you uninstall it, both "CSF" and "LFD" will be effected...
2. Moreover, I can do `sudo apt-get install fail2ban` even though I already installed CSF (and LFD?) in the above way.

The combination of these two facts confuses me because from these data I can't be sure if this setup also installs LFD and if it is, must there be a conflict with Fail2Ban.

---

Given what I described, my question can be comprised of these two:

1. Does the above installation installs **both** CSF and LFD?
2. Is Fail2Ban installed via `sudo apt-get install fail2ban` actually the same as the above LFD (that may or may not be installed) and if so, musn't there be a conflict between the two?

Comment: You do have LFD, it's installed with CSF. I recommend this doc for learning about that: https://download.configserver.com/csf/readme.txt ... LFD and fail2ban are two separate things. I am wondering the same thing, if there will be a conflict installing fail2ban alongside it. Looking forward to seeing what folks have to say about that. I am concerned about fail2ban conflicting with CSF/LFD's control of the firewall.

Comment: My Bounty ends in 3 days: If you see fit and have some spare time, you are invited to write an answer and I'll gladly give you the bounty...

Comment: Thanks, I added an answer and hope it is good enough for you to award the bounty and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been investigating this some more and can answer reasonably well now. Answers to each part of the question:

1. Yes, LFD is installed as part of CSF. You have LFD installed if you use that process.
2. Fail2ban is NOT the same as LFD and there IS a conflict. You should not use them both. Using CSF and LFD is all you need and fail2ban would only be an alternative to some parts of LFD.

So I recommend you use CSF, which includes LFD, and do not install fail2ban. I also highly recommend reading the readme file for CSF/LFD at:
https://download.configserver.com/csf/readme.txt